# Why does PyCharm return exit code 246?

Tags: python, pycharm, arcpy

I am running a script in PyCharm and using the Python 3 installation that is installed with ArcGIS Pro.

Every other time I run the code, it returns "exit code 246", but it is not clear to me what could be causing this.

If I close and reopen the program or restart my computer, I might be able to run the code, but it doesn't work consistently.

The issue doesn't happen consistently so I don't think it's an issue with the code itself.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, or any other details?

Comment: This is all that shows in the stack trace..."C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" U:/CensusAPIRequest.py

Process finished with exit code 246

Comment: Did you look at the memory consumption during the invocation? Maybe it is running out of memory and gets terminated because of that?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/331875/115

Comment: So nothing to do with Pycharm - It is a Python/library error, and it isn't PyCharm is exiting at all.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the same problem.  Problem went away when I did this

```
try:
  import arcpy
except:
```

Comment: How can that be the solution ? It isn't legal syntax since there is no code-suite after the except ?